# shell script to remove last character of a line

Tags: shell

Below is my string,

```
1,abmc,fdsaf.,sdfsd,
```

My output should be as below

> 1,abmc,fdsaf.,sdfsd

(,) should be **removed**

Should implement using `shell` please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution with `sed`

```
echo "1,abmc,fdsaf.,sdfsd," | sed 's/.$//g'
```

output:

```
1,abmc,fdsaf.,sdfsd
```

Explanation:

- `s/.$//g` --> replaces `.(any character)` at the end of line with nothing (empty string).

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will work for you

```
 word="1,abmc,fdsaf.,sdfsd,"
 echo ${word%?}
```

`%` is bash parameter substitution operator,by using `?` we instruct bash to match any character at the end of the variable and remove it.